# How to show ModelState.AddModelError when the Model is Empty in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am displaying a shopping cart. I need to check for empty values in Shopping cart and display a message like "The Shopping Cart is empty".

When I use ModelState.AddModelError in myAction, it throws an exception as there is null reference in Model. How to display the ErrorMessage.
My Action

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string id = Request.QueryString["UserID"];
            IList<CartModel> objshop = new List<CartModel>();
            objshop = GetCartDetails(id);
            if (objshop.Count > 0)
            {
                return View(objshop.ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your Shopping Cart is empty!");
            }
            return View();
}
```

My View

```
    @{
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     }

 <th > @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductName) </th>
 <th > @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)   </th>
 <th > @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rate)      </th>
 <th > @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)    </th>        
 @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
<td>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)</td>
<td>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)</td>
<td>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rate) </td>
<td>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price) </td>
   }
```

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last line in your Action like this:

```
return View(new List<CartModel>());
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your not passing an empty model in when there is nothing in the cart therefore your `ModelState` has nothing to attach itself to. However, it doesn't make sense to treat this as an *error*, it's perfectly valid for the shopping cart to be empty. Instead, I would handle the empty model in your view directly e.g.

**Action**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string id = Request.QueryString["UserID"];
    IList<CartModel> objshop = new List<CartModel>();
    // assuming GetCartDetails returns an empty list & not null if there is nothing
    objshop = GetCartDetails(id);
    return View(objshop.ToList());
}
```

**View**

```
@model IList<CardModel>

@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    <p>Your shopping cart is empty!</p>
}
```